# Django ModelForm Multiple Ajax ModelChoiceFiels based on ForeignKey is_valid error

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, django-forms

I have been working on a register form using ModelForm in Django. I want to create two choice fields, one is linked with the first one and refreshed by ajax. Using multiple examples and questions from stackoverflow i have build a solution but there is still one issue that remains.

- The first choice field you choose the company.
- The second choice field you choose the address of the company

When the form loads i want the second choice field to be empty. So i have used a queryset pointing to none.

```
self.fields['company_address'].queryset = Company_address.objects.none()
```

I populate this choice field when the user selects the company. The ajax request works properly. But when i submit the form i get an error :

> Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.

If  i don't override the content of the company address choice field, the form validation works properly. I think the problem comes from the definition of the Form but i don't find the answer.

Thanks in advance for your help !

**views.py:**

```
def register(request):
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/entreprises/')
else:
    context = RequestContext(request)
    registered = False
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
        profile_form = UserProfileForm(data=request.POST)
        print request.POST
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()
            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user
            profile.save()
            registered = True
        else:
            print user_form.errors, profile_form.errors
    else:
        user_form = UserForm()
        profile_form = UserProfileForm()

    return render_to_response(
            'entreprises/register.html',
            {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form, 'registered': registered},
            context)
```

**forms.py:**

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
company = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Company.objects.all(), required=True)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(UserProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['company_address'].required = True
    self.fields['company_address'].queryset = Company_address.objects.none()
    self.fields['accepted_eula'].required = True

class Meta:
    model = UserProfile
    fields = ('company','company_address','accepted_eula')
    widgets = {
        'company_address': forms.Select(attrs={'name': 'company_address'}),
    }
```

**models.py:**

```
class Company(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Nom')
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name
class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'Entreprises'

class Company_address(models.Model):
company = models.ForeignKey(Company, verbose_name='Entreprise')
country = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Pays')
def __unicode__(self):
    return unicode(self.country)
class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'Adresses d\'entreprise'

class UserProfile(models.Model):
# This field is required.
user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='UserProfile_entreprises')

# Other fields here
company_address = models.ForeignKey(Company_address, verbose_name='Adresses d\'entreprise')
accepted_eula = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**ajax.js:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('select[name=company]').change(function(){
    //$('select[name=company]').children('option:first').remove();
    $('select[name=company_address]').empty();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../get_register_company_address/',
        data: {
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value,
            company_id: $(this).val(),
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            alert(data);
            $.each(data, function(key, value){
                $('select[name=company_address]').append('<option value="' + key + '">' + value +'</option>');
            });
        }
        //return false;
    })
})
});
```